# How do you use user input for characters in a calculation?

Tags: java, input, char

How can you take in a sign (*, +, or -) and use that in a calculation in java? Example:

```
int n = 10;
int f = 10;
//sign is the user input for the character to be used in the calculation.

/* Insert something along the lines of int r = f sign n;
   if sign is equal to '-', then the result should be 0, 
   if sign is '+', result should be 20. 
   etc. */
```

Comment: use `if-else` or `switch-case` statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read the user's input, and then use either the `if..else if.. else` condition or a `switch` statement to perform the arithmetic.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String operator = scanner.nextLine();
switch (operator) {
  case "+":
    r = f + n;
    break;
  case "-": 
    r = f - n;
    break;
  case "*":
    r = f * n;
    break;
  case "/":
    r = f / n;
    break;
  default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operators.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user to input the sign and store it to variable. For e.g., variable sign. Use condition statements. like:

```
if (sign=='+')
  r=n+f;
else if (sign=='e')
  r=n-f;
else if (sign=='*')
  r=n*f;
```

or use switch case.